# Pascal case error for dynamically adding component name to Reactjs Route's render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx

I am trying to get a component to render dynamically. The name for the component is getting pulled from the state. The name is in pascal case but still it throws a pascal case error. For instance, the value that I am trying on is "HeroBanner". If I put this directly, it works fine. If get this dynamically via state and then assigning it to a variable, it backfires with pascal case error.

Here's my code

```
import '@babel/polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import HeroBanner from './IssueList.jsx';
import IssueTable from './IssueTable.jsx';
import {PropTypes} from 'prop-types';
import {Header} from './Header.jsx';
import Demo from './Cropcrop.jsx';
import {Receiver} from 'react-file-uploader';

const contentNode = document.querySelector("#contents");
const NoMatch = () => <p>404 no result</p>

class App extends  React.Component{
    
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            currentLocation: ""
        }
        
        this.changeLocation = this.changeLocation.bind(this)
    }
    
    changeLocation(e){
        
        this.setState({
            currentLocation: e
        })
        
    }
    
    render(){
        
        const Component= this.state.currentLocation === ''? "HeroBanner" : this.state.currentLocation
        
        return(
                <div>
                    <BrowserRouter>
                        <Header/>
                          <Redirect from="/" to="/selection"></Redirect>
                            <Switch>
                                <Route exact path={"/"+ Component} render={(props) => <Component />} />
                                <Route exact path="/selection" render={(props) => <IssueTable {...props} onChange={this.changeLocation} />}  />
                                <Route  path="/*" component={NoMatch}/>
                                </Switch>
                     </BrowserRouter>
                <Component/>
                </div>
        )
        }

        }





const RoutedApp = () => (
    <App/>
);


ReactDOM.render(<RoutedApp />, contentNode);

if(module.hot){
    module.hot.accept();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not allowed to specify component dynamically like this in React (specifying a string instead of a type):

`render={(props) => <Component />}`

It should be something like:

`const Component = this.state.currentLocation === '' ? HeroBanner : SomeOtherComponent;`

I had a similar situation in the project I'm working on and ended up with creating a map between a certain string value (in my case it was the name of a tab, coming from the URL) and component's type:

```
const componentsMap = {
   home: HomeComponent,
   about: AboutComponent,
   ...
}

const Component = componentsMap[myStringValue];
```

That last piece of code is allowed as you're refering to the **component's type**, not to some ordinary string which can't be used as valid JSX.

---

**As for routing**, I noticed you just set some string value in the state and expect routing to happen. This is not the case as `react-router-dom` listens for changes in the browser's url/path and you should probably perform manual routing in your case to move to another `<Route>` view. In the example below I perform navigation in the `onDropdownChange` handler upon dropdown change.

The way I like to minimize repetition of strings representing route names and component names is to have the dynamic value as param in the URL. Then a `<Subroute>` component handles all the mapping for that group of routes (you might not need that additional level of nesting, depends on size of app). In the sandbox I created you can see the map I was talking about in the comments. You select the appropriate component based on the `tab` param in the URL (which holds the value selected from the dropdown).

[Example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-http-e9852)

---

**EDIT for a question in the comments (11 Aug 2020):**

You can also use a neat trick to customize what gets rendered by a route, like this (without having to use render of Route):

```
<Route exact path={path}>
   <ComponentOne {...someProps} />
   <ComponentTwo {...someOtherProps} />
   <p>Some html too</p>
</Route>
```

To use `render` instead (maybe less readable, I prefer the first option, just pass the necessary JSX, wrapped in `Fragment` if needed):

```
<Route
    exact
    render={routeProps => (
        <Fragment>
            <ComponentOne {...someProps} />
            <ComponentTwo {...someOtherProps} />
            <p>Some html too</p>
        </Fragment>
    )}
/>
```

Comment: thanks, that make sense, but lets say I am getting the component name from `<option/>` element's `name` attribute's value and assigning it to a state `currentLocation`. Obviously this will return a String value. How do you suppose I can convert that string to a component name?

Comment: You'll need to have a pre-defined map object, where the key is the option from the dropdown element (**string**) and the component specified as symbol (**not string**). Mayble you'll end up with a bunch of similar looking strings like:

**heroBanner (string value) : HeroBanner (symbol)**

Hopefully, you don't have much values from the dropdown, that is more than 10. In the case I mention in my answer, we have 6 different tabs, but they don't match one to one (tab name and component name).

Comment: I am confused, what kind of symbol are you referring to? Can you give some example. Let me also rephrase - I am already using `map` function to allocate the different options. I am specifying the component name I want to route as the `option` `name` attribute. onChange I am getting the value of the `name` and assigning it to a variable with name `Component` in the above code. So that I can see that selected component from the dropdown

Comment: By symbol I mean refering to the component's name statically, without any quotes and strings, as if you define the class: **HeroBanner** and not **"HeroBanner"**. 
You can't write ```const ComponentName = someStringVariable``` and use it like JSX tag: ```<ComponentName />```. That's why I suggested to create a hardcoded map of string and component type and get the component type from there by writing ```const Component = myMap[valueFromDropdown]```. That IS allowed as now you refer to component type, not an ordinary string.

Comment: That's fine. My answer actually states that what you're asking for currently can't be done in React. :) I can create a small sandbox if you want me to show something.

Comment: Just came to me, how do you think we can pass props in this case? If I use render method for Route @RosenDimov

Comment: Yes!, I also figured it out yesterday. :))

Answer (score 0):

While the above answer is absolutely correct. Here's how I followed the above the logic.

```
import '@babel/polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import HeroBanner from './IssueList.jsx';
import IssueTable from './IssueTable.jsx';
import {PropTypes} from 'prop-types';
import {Header} from './Header.jsx';
import Demo from './Cropcrop.jsx';
import {Receiver} from 'react-file-uploader';
const contentNode = document.querySelector("#contents");
const NoMatch = () => <p>404 no result</p>

const componentList={
    HeroBanner: HeroBanner
}

class RoutedApp extends  React.Component{
    
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            currentLocation: ""
        }
        
        this.changeLocation = this.changeLocation.bind(this)
    }
    
    changeLocation(e){
        console.log(e)
        this.setState({
            currentLocation: e
        })
        
    }
    
    render(){
        
        const Component= this.state.currentLocation === '' ? NoMatch : componentList[this.state.currentLocation]
        console.log(Component)
        return(
                <div>
                    <BrowserRouter>
                        <Header/>
                          <Redirect from="/" to="/selection"></Redirect>
                            <Switch>
                                <Route exact path={"/"+ this.state.currentLocation} component={Component} />
                                <Route exact path="/selection" render={(props) => <IssueTable {...props} onChange={this.changeLocation} />}  />
                                <Route  path="/*" component={NoMatch}/>
                                </Switch>
                     </BrowserRouter>
             </div>
        )
     }
 }




ReactDOM.render(<RoutedApp />, contentNode);

if(module.hot){
    module.hot.accept();
}
```